# How to generate count and percent for indicator variable?

Tags: r, dataframe

I am looking to create summary statistics that give a count and percentage for an indicator variable when another indicator is equal to 1. In the table below, I am looking to get a count of how many times NYAL 08B is equal to one and zero when NYAL 08 is equal to 1. Further, I am looking for a percentage of the time that NYAL 08B is equal to one when NYAL 08 is equal to one.

```
Layer       Grade       Players             Var 2      NYAL 08     NYAL 08B    
Top           A         NYAL 08; NYAL 27   NYAL 08        1           1
Bottom        D         MAAC 27; MAAC 45   NYAL 27        0           0 
Middle        B         NYAL 08; MAAC 48   NYAL 27        1           0
```

For the above table, I'm looking for an output similar to this:

```
`NYAL 08` Count  Perc
1          1      50
0          1      50
```

I have tried the following code, but it doesn't seem to work.

```
df %>% 
group_by(`NYAL 08`) %>% 
summarise(Count = sum(`NYAL 08B`)) %>% 
mutate(Perc = Count/sum(Count))
```

Comment: Providing some sample data would help! https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `filter` to keep only rows where `NYAL 08 == 1` and use `count` to calculate number and `prop.table` for proportions.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  filter(`NYAL 08` == 1) %>%
  count(`NYAL 08B`) %>%
  mutate(perc = prop.table(n) * 100)

#  NYAL 08B n perc
#1        0 1   50
#2        1 1   50
```

---

For many such variables we can use `map` and apply the same code for each pair.

```
cols <- c('NYAL 08',  'NYAL 27')

purrr::map(cols, ~df %>%
      filter(.data[[.x]] == 1) %>%
      count(.data[[paste0(.x, 'B')]]) %>%
      mutate(perc = prop.table(n) * 100))
```

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(Layer = c("Top", "Bottom", "Middle"), Grade = c("A", 
"D", "B"), Players = c("NYAL 08; NYAL 27", "MAAC 27; MAAC 45", 
"NYAL 08; MAAC 48"), `Var 2` = c("NYAL 08", "NYAL 27", "NYAL 27"
), `NYAL 08` = c(1L, 0L, 1L), `NYAL 08B` = c(1L, 0L, 0L)), 
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))
```

Comment: Is there another way to do it besides subsetting? I have quite a few indicator variables (abbreviated the data set to conserve space here).

Comment: @rogues77 See updated answer to apply this for multiple variables.